# C++ Xerces Parser Load HTML and Search for HTML Elements

Tags: c++, html, domdocument, xerces

Im trying to load HTML with Xerces DOMDocument C++ Parser and search for specific HTML Elements. I am having trouble finding good examples on how to accomplish this. All I seem to find is parsing XML. Can someone assist? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/program-dom-3.html

There is an example with DOMDocument as well:

//
    //  Create a small document tree
    //

```
{
    XMLCh tempStr[100];

    XMLString::transcode("Range", tempStr, 99);
    DOMImplementation* impl = DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(tempStr, 0);

    XMLString::transcode("root", tempStr, 99);
    DOMDocument*   doc = impl->createDocument(0, tempStr, 0);
    DOMElement*   root = doc->getDocumentElement();

    XMLString::transcode("FirstElement", tempStr, 99);
    DOMElement*   e1 = doc->createElement(tempStr);
    root->appendChild(e1);

    XMLString::transcode("SecondElement", tempStr, 99);
    DOMElement*   e2 = doc->createElement(tempStr);
    root->appendChild(e2);

    XMLString::transcode("aTextNode", tempStr, 99);
    DOMText*       textNode = doc->createTextNode(tempStr);
    e1->appendChild(textNode);

    // optionally, call release() to release the resource associated with the range after done
    DOMRange* range = doc->createRange();
    range->release();

    // removedElement is an orphaned node, optionally call release() to release associated resource
    DOMElement* removedElement = root->removeChild(e2);
    removedElement->release();

    // no need to release this returned object which is owned by implementation
    XMLString::transcode("*", tempStr, 99);
    DOMNodeList*    nodeList = doc->getElementsByTagName(tempStr);

    // done with the document, must call release() to release the entire document resources
    doc->release();
};
```

... and so long.

EDIT:

> But how do I load HTML into the DOMDocument and search against the html elements? 
>   Thats what Im trying to figure out.

XercesDOMParser parser;

parser.loadGrammar("grammar.dtd", Grammar::DTDGrammarType);

parser.setValidationScheme(XercesDOMParser::Val_Always);

Handler handler;

parser.setErrorHandler( &handler );

parser.parse("xmlfile.xml");

Comment: But how do I load HTML into the DOMDocument and search against the html elements? Thats what Im trying to figure out.